# Does bash search with regex?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, syntax, sh

Does bash search with regex?

For example, if I wanted to do a for loop that go through all the files of the current directory that start with the letter `a`, would the following work?

```
for x in a.*
do
```

Comment: I did, and it works if there are such files and when there aren't... @Gumbo

Comment: shell uses `glob` instead of serious regex. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to *filename expansion*, the *[ABS](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)* states:

> Bash itself cannot recognize Regular Expressions. 
> Inside scripts, it
>   is commands and utilities -- such as `sed` and `awk` -- that interpret
>   RE's.
>
> Bash *does* carry out filename expansion -- a process known as
>   *globbing*, but this does not use the standard RE set. Instead, globbing recognizes and expands *wild cards*.

*[More on wildcards.](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)*

However, as mentioned by *[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)*, bash *DOES* support [regex](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) outside of `filename expansion` context:

```
(digit=5; [[ $digit =~ [0-9] ]] && echo match)
```

Coming back to the OP's question, to loop over all files starting with `a`:

```
for x in a* ; do
    [[ -f "$x" ]] || continue
    # process x
done
```

Comment: I guess that the OP was also wondering how to loop through all files beginning with `a`.

Comment: So I want to search for "globbing" for the syntax of doing things similar to my example?

Comment: Note that globbing has a different syntax than regular expresions. The original question was whether `a.*` will match all files that start with `a`. With globbing, this is not true, as the `.` has to match a literal `.`, and the `*` will match anything, so this will match `a.txt`, `a.out`, etc., but would not match `ab.txt`. To match anything starting with `a`, use `a*`.

Comment: @Tom, Kristopher: I've answered the second part of the question. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: So just to make sure, regex syntax is only for `grep` for example, and for other commands like `rm` I should use globbing syntax.

Comment: @kuhaku, Read the linked documentation and also read [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)!  Also in [PDF format](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf).

Comment: Once again, the ABS gets it wrong (or at least words it poorly): `bash` does recognize regular expressions (`[[ foo =~ fo* ]] && echo match`), just not in this context.

Comment: @Eugeniu Rosca, Your `for` loop as written will act on everything in the directory, files, directories, symlinks etc.  Since the OP stated "files" then maybe add a conditional `if` statement inside the `for` loop. E.g.: `if [[ -f "$x" ]] then; ...; fi`

Comment: @user3439894 /chepner: Answer updated based on your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Why the double brackets in `if [[ -f "$x" ]]` ?

Comment: @user3439894 why the double brackets in `if [[ -f "$x" ]]`?

Comment: @kuhaku, As I've already suggested, **read the documentation**! In this case more specifically, [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) & [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: Single brackets `[` is a shell builtin known as `test` and does filename expansions.  Double brackets `[[` is a shell keyword and performs *pattern matching* , it comes originally from korn shell.   Bash supports *extended globbing*, see `shopt`, and extended regular expressions using the binding operator `=~`.   BTW, @user3439894 you don't need to quote `"$x"` inside `[[` (even if the value contains embedded whitespace), but you do inside `[`.

Comment: @cdarke, I know that and I do it out of the habit of quoting variables in general and it does not cause the test to fail, so I don't see it as big deal.